# Does Trappist-1 have a Periodic Configuration?

Tags: orbit, exoplanet, trappist-1

Trappist-1's planetary system is notable for having 7 planets in a resonance chain. I would think, since all the planets are in resonance, the system would have a repeating configuration that could be diagramed, but I do not see any of these diagrams online, only a statement from one source that "For every 2 orbits of the outermost planet, the next planet inward orbits 3 times, the next one 4, then 6, 9, 15 and 24 times." This statement would seem to infer that the configuration repeats every 2 orbits of the outer planet, 3 orbits of the next, 4 orbits, 6, 9, 15, 24 orbits of the respective planets. This resonance chain, given the length of the orbital periods, should result in the planetary system repeating it's configuration every 36-38 earth days, but I have seen no explicit information stating the length of the systems period. I did find somewhere else that the gravitational interactions between the planets cause each planet to speed up or slow down an hour every orbit, but if this did not occur, would the system periodically reconfigure? Is my timescale correct?

Comment: related: [Just how "locked" are resonant-chains of exoplanets thought to be? (e.g. K2-138 and TOI-178)](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/23980/7982) and your previous question [How often does the configuration of the Trappist-1 system repeat](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/47173/7982) Also, [this answer to *Are there any planned future observations of TRAPPIST-1 and its planets?*](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/20181/7982) links to the website http://www.trappist.one/